# Using Ethereum to buy Tezos

Tags: ether, calldata, tezos

I would like to use my Ethereum to buy Tezos.
Does anyone know if Coinbase pass transaction data along with the transaction?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use exchanges for ico. As soon as Tezo ICO starts they will have instructions but I'm sure you will have to move it to an Ethereum wallet.

Regards,

Tina Dobson